# Angular 9 cannot filter date after date pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I have a problem with date filtering using [(ngModel)]. I call backend with HTTP service and get JSON with dates in the format like 2020-12-11T08:53:13.313+0000. Next, I'm using the pipe to transform this date to format: 2020-12-11 09:53 (+ 1 hour in my time zone). But when I try to filter this date by input with ngModel it doesn't work correctly. For example, when I enter values like 2020-08-03 15:36 I've got an empty search, but when I enter values like 2020-08-03T14:36 it works correctly. Where is the problem?

Here is my date pipe:

```
     <tr *ngFor="let data of myProcess | filter:search1">
       <td>{{data.finishDate  | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}</td>
       <td>{{data.serviceCode | serviceName}}</td>
```

and my fiter input:

```
<div class="col" style="padding: 0px;">
    <input class="form-control2" type="text" name="searchField" [(ngModel)]="search1" autocomplete="on"
      placeholder="Filtruj procesy" style="width: 250px !important;">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The date pipe is only formatting the value shown on `<td>`, it doesn't change the contents of your list data. So the value sent to the search1 is not formatted.
There are some ways to fix this, one is to apply the same date pipe inside your filter pipe. You can have a constructor inside the filter pipe and inject the DatePipe there.

One example of a way to filter a list of dates:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-filter-date-list?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html